# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in MYFILE on line 16

Tags: php

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /MYFILE/ on line 16

My code

```
    <?php
session_start();
global $module, $id; 
require_once '../includes/connection.php';
include('xcrud/xcrud.php');
$module = $_GET["module"]; 
$id = $_GET["id"];
include "xcrud/modules/$module.php";
if((!isset ($_SESSION['user']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['password']) == true)){
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    unset($_SESSION['password']);
    header('location:index.php');
} else {
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>";
            include 'theme/head.html';  
        echo "</head>
        <body>";
        include 'theme/bodya.html';
        include "modules/$module.php";
        include 'theme/bodyb.html'; 
            echo "</body>
    </html>";
}
?>
```

Comment: are you sure thats the code with the error?

Comment: Yes, i dont know whats happens, i already use this code, without problem, but now i get this error from log

Comment: i see no error, i suspect its not the actaul code

Comment: `MYFILE` being what? what you posted one of the other files that are included/required

Comment: This code have no errors. Check other files, you've missed escaping somewhere \" or \'.

Comment: Btw, this `if((!isset ($_SESSION['user']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['password']) == true))` you're creating 2 false positives.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The problem happens because my host. SOme kind a cache problem. Now i see the true code

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang='en'>
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">";

Comment: thanks for alert about false positives Fred.

Comment: Here is it, unescaped content. Glad that you've found your problem.